# Anylogic, dynamic variable array with different stocks as elements

Tags: arrays, anylogic

I want to use a dynamic variable to concatenate the values of multiple stocks. I tried a couple of different methods I could think of to phrase the formula but this was the result each time.[image]
The examples for arrays in Anylogic I found online all try to split up one element in multiple array entries by using a formula akin to dynamicVariable = stock * fractionArray[stockTypes] with an array of constant inputs, that splits up a single input stock. I couldn't find anything on how to actually assign different variables to different array elements.

The answer is probably really simple but I'm pretty stuck here, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do this, you need to separate your array elements as follows:
[image: dimensions]

Just click on stockTypes to select one of the options and then add formula to have the other option